Shouldn't an overridden function in a derived class cause a compile error if it changes the constness of the function return type?
I have a base class with an abstract function declared to return a reference to a const object.  Disturbingly, a derived class overrides that function but changes the return type to a reference to a mutable object.  This still compiles, even though the derived class uses the "override" keyword.
Does the C++ standard actually allow this, or is this a compiler error?
An example which reproduces this is given below:
struct Widget
{
    int x = 42;
};

struct Base
{
    virtual const Widget & GetWidget() = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    virtual const Widget & GetWidget() override
    {
        return m_widget;
    }
private:
    Widget m_widget;
};

struct DerivedAgain : public Derived
{
    virtual /* missing "const"*/ Widget & GetWidget() override // Shouldn't compile?
    {
        return m_widgetAgain;
    }
private:
    Widget m_widgetAgain;
};

void main()
{
    DerivedAgain thing;

    thing.GetWidget().x = 666; // Shouldn't be allowed?
}

What I tried:  Compiling the source file
What I expected:  Compiler error
What actually resulted:  Compiles with no errors
Build started at 11:33 AM...
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Test.cpp
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 11:33 AM and took 00.301 seconds ==========


The returned type must be covariant. p.e. const Widget& then Widget& or Widget& then DerivedFromWidget& is valid, but not the opposite. Here if Derived returns a reference to not const, then DerivedAgain must also returns a reference  to not const.

Thank you all for the responses and the link to the question I (unwittingly) duplicated.  I was previously aware of covariance but didn't know cv-qualification could be altered by it.  That it can seems like fertile ground for bugs and difficult-to-solve software engineering issues (e.g. perhaps a subtle way to violate the 'L' in SOLID)!

@GEORanger what issue do you see with the L? Afaik covariance is in accordance with L in general, and const foo&  x = base_ref.GetWidget(); is also fine. In your example you are explicitly constructing a DerivedAgain. If you had a pointer/reference to Base and you call GetWidget you get a const Widget & (unless you are already outside of L)
